# Don't allow java doc comments for license headers using the apache-rat-plugin

Tags: java, maven

The apache-rat-plugin allows license headers to be both in normal comments and java doc comments at the top of my class files. How can I only allow license headers to be in a normal comment, and NOT in a java doc comment?

My plugin configuration is the following;

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>rat-checks</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <excludeSubprojects>false</excludeSubprojects>
      <excludes>
         <!-- my excludes here -->
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be configurable with the apache-rat-plugin. I will have to use the license-maven-plugin instead.